# Access LookUp table

Tags: ms-access, lookup-tables

i need to create a lookup table in Access, where all the abbreviations are related to a value, and if the abbreviation (in the main table) is null, then i want to show "Unknown"

i got the values working, but i can't seem to get the nulls to show up.

my lookup table looks like this:

```
REQUEST     REQUEST_TEXT
------------------------
A           Approve
D           Disapprove
NULL        N/A
```

but when i do a count by request, it only shows me values for A and D, all though i know there are some blanks in there as well.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be easier if you change tblLookup.

```
REQUEST     REQUEST_TEXT
------------------------
A           Approve
D           Disapprove
U           Unknown
```

Then, in tblMain, change the REQUEST field to Required = True and Default Value = "U".  When new records are added, they will have U for REQUEST unless the user changes it to A or D.

Then a query which JOINs the 2 tables on REQUEST should get you what I think you want.

```
SELECT m.REQUEST, l.REQUEST_TEXT
FROM tblMain AS m
    INNER JOIN tblLookup AS l
    ON l.REQUEST = m.REQUEST;
```

You should also create a relationship between the 2 tables, and select the option to enforce referential integrity in order to prevent the users from adding a spurious value such as "X" for REQUEST.

**Edit**:
If changing tblMain structure is off the table, and if you're doing this from within an Access session, you can use the Nz() function on a LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT m.REQUEST, Nz(l.REQUEST_TEXT, "Unknown")
FROM tblMain AS m
    LEFT JOIN tblLookup AS l
    ON l.REQUEST = m.REQUEST;
```

If you're doing this from outside an Access session, like from ASP, the Nz() function will not be available.  So you can substitute an IIf() expression for Nz().

```
SELECT m.REQUEST, IIf(l.REQUEST_TEXT Is Null, "Unknown", l.REQUEST_TEXT)
FROM tblMain AS m
    LEFT JOIN tblLookup AS l
    ON l.REQUEST = m.REQUEST;
```

**Edit2**: You can't directly JOIN with Null values.  However with the "Unknown" row I suggested for tblLookup, you could use a JOIN which includes Nz for tblMain.REQUEST

```
SELECT m.id, m.request, l.request_text
FROM tblMain AS m
    INNER JOIN tblLookup AS l
    ON Nz(m.request,"U") = l.request;
```

If you want to leave tblLookup REQUEST as Null for REQUEST_TEXT = Unknown,  I suppose you could use Nz on both sides of the JOIN expression.  However, this whole idea of joining Nulls makes me cringe.  I would fix the tables instead.

Comment: i can't change anything in the tblMain, is there a way to create a tblLookup to give me Unknown for all nulls?

Comment: You could create a query called "qryMain" that duplicates tblMain except that shows Unknown instead of Nulls. Then your other tables would do the lookup using qryMain instead of tblMain